# recyclerview endless scrolling slowdown

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I read this guide on implementing [endless scrolling](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) and tried it.  Here is my implementation of loadNextDataFromApi:

```
public void loadNextDataFromApi(int page, String term) {
    movieService.getMovies(page, term)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Movie> currentPageMovies) {
                    int start = allMovies.size();
                    allMovies.addAll(currentPageMovies);
                    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(start, currentPageMovies.size());
                }
            });
}
```

allMovies holds all the movies for a given search.  This works fine initially but scrolling eventually loads slower, from smooth scrolling to 3 movies at a time(the number specified for every request).  I think this is because the list grows and takes up an increasing amount of memory.  The article mentions,

> In order for the pagination system to continue working reliably, you should make sure to clear the adapter of items (or notify adapter after clearing the array) before appending new items to the list

But changing the onNext implementation above to this breaks the endless scroll:

```
            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Movie> currentPageMovies) {
                allMovies.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                int start = allMovies.size();
                allMovies.addAll(currentPageMovies);
                adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(start, currentPageMovies.size());
            }
```

Wouldn't you need to keep previous pages of List in the allMovies list for scrolling back up?  At the same time doing so with an endless scroll can lead to OOM depending on the number of pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have worked on endless scrolling with api calling so i can share my code with you, as i found my list is doing well.

First use this method to get recyclerview has reached last position.

```
public void setRecyclerViewLastPositionListner(RecyclerView rv, final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager, final OnLastPositionReached onLastPositionReached) {
    rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                userScrolled = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            // Here get the child count, item count and visibleitems
            // from layout manager

            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            // Now check if userScrolled is true and also check if
            // the item is end then update recycler view and set
            // userScrolled to false
            if (userScrolled && (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) == totalItemCount) {
                userScrolled = false;
                if (onLastPositionReached != null) onLastPositionReached.onReached();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here interfaced used

```
public interface OnLastPositionReached {
    void onReached();
}
```

Use it like

```
UtilitiesV2.getInstance().setRecyclerViewLastPositionListner(yourRecyclerView, mLayoutManager, new UtilitiesV2.OnLastPositionReached() {
            @Override
            public void onReached() {
                callEBookApi();
            }
        });
```

These variables holds start position for next api calling.

```
  long start = 0;
    private int lastReceivedListSize = 0;
      int DEFAULT_LIMIT = 20;
```

consider calling your api here.

```
 private void callEBookApi() {
        start = booksAdapter.getItemCount();
        if (start != 0 & lastReceivedListSize < DEFAULT_LIMIT)
            return;
        BeanLimit beanLimit = new BeanLimit();
        beanLimit.setLimit(DEFAULT_LIMIT);
        beanLimit.setStartpoint(start);
        showProgressBar();
        try {
            callWebServicePost(Interactor.RequestCode_getEbooks, Interactor.Tag_getEbooks, Interactor.Method_getEbooks, new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(beanLimit)), false, new OnResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int requestCode, Response responsePacket) {

                    hideProgressBar();

                        ArrayList<BookBean> list = responsePacket.getResponsePacket().getBooksList();
                        lastReceivedListSize = list.size();
                        updateListData(list);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int requestCode, ErrorType errorType) {
                    FragmentEbooks.super.onError(requestCode, errorType);
                    hideProgressBar();
                    UtilProject.getInstance().showNothingToDisplayLayout(FragmentEbooks.this);
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    }




    private void updateListData(ArrayList<BookBean> list) {
        if (list == null) listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
        booksAdapter.insertItemsInList(list);
        if (booksAdapter.getList().size() != 0) {
           // UtilProject.getInstance().hideNothingToDisplayAndProgressBar(this);   /*here you show placeholder if list empty*/
        } else {
           // UtilProject.getInstance().showNothingToDisplayLayout(this);
        }
    }





    public void insertItemsInList(ArrayList<InvitationBean> myList) {
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastIndex = list.size();
        list.addAll(myList);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(lastIndex, myList.size());  /*use this line for smooth scrolling if you use notifyDataSetChanged it will load all data again*/
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you but you are still constantly appending query results to the larger list just like in the solution I posted.  You will eventually get an OOM exception and slowdown of loading

Comment: So you want an solution in that list object has only like max 100 items at once. and it get older one with scrolling. 
I think you can manage it. 
If you like to do so you can just manage an databse(like sugar) in which your list is stored and you can fetch data from database and load. 
You can do it man.